# Store an Array to access on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, mobile

I am using HTML5 to create a web app and am storing information to access on different html pages with:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("variable");
```

I am able to share simple strings between pages. Is there a way to store an array that I can add to and delete from on different pages in javascript?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` does wonders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object to encode and decode the array to and from a string.

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

localStorage.setItem('myItem', JSON.stringify(myArr));

var val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItem'));

console.log(val);
```

Comment: will JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItem')); put it back into an array?

Comment: Yes. Paste that code in your browser's console - it logs the `val` variable, which will be an array.

Comment: awesome about to try this

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('variable'));
localStorage.setItem('variable', JSON.stringify(yourArray));
```